# Queue Linked List with Menu

Tags: java, data-structures, computer-science

I am trying to fix my program to make it run better and I have some code issues with it.Option 3 and 4 suffer from runtime exception error when applied on empty queue, how can I check for this? For a nonempty queue, option 4 shows “Queue is empty, exception thrown” followed by correct answer (“Last item in queue is: “). Option 5 (size) returns 1 on empty queue. Should be 0. In fact, it returns 1 more than size. Also, how do I make the menu repeat, it is annoying to enter ‘c’ after each operation. Bellow is my java code:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class QueueMenu {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      int b; 
      int c;


      String cont = "c";


      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);


      QueueLL newq = new QueueLL();


      while(cont.equals("c"))
      {

         System.out.println("I   Insert an item to the queue (at rear)");
         System.out.println("II  Delete an item from the queue (from front)");
         System.out.println("III Display the item at front");
         System.out.println("IV  Display the item at rear");
         System.out.println("V   Display total number of items currently present in the queue");
         System.out.println("VI  Print the items currently present in the queue");
         System.out.println("VII Quit");

         b = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
         switch(b)
         {


            case 1: 
               System.out.print("Enter an integer number: ");
               c = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
               newq.insert(c);
               break;

            case 2:
               c = newq.remove();
               System.out.print("Enter an integer number: " + c);
               break;



            case 3:
               c = newq.displayQF();
               System.out.print("First item in Queue is: \n" + c);
               break;


            case 4: 
               c = newq.displayQR();
               if(c != 0)
                  System.out.print("Last item in Queue is:  \n" + c);
               else
                  System.out.print("The Queue is empty");
               break;

            case 5: 
               c = newq.count();
               System.out.println("Total number of elements currently present in the queue are: \n" + c);
               break;



            case 6: 
               System.out.println("Elements currently present in the queue are: \n" );
               newq.displayQ();
               break;


            case 7: 
               System.exit(0);
               System.out.println("Quit\n");
               break;



            default:
               System.out.println("What you have entered is not accepted by the system.Please retry");
               break;

         }

         System.out.println("  ");
         System.out.println("Enter c to continue or  q to end program");
         cont = in.readLine();

      }


   }    

}
```

```css
public class QueueLL {

   int  count = 1;

   SinglyLinkedListQueue sllq = new SinglyLinkedListQueue();


   public int count(){

      return count;

   }

   public boolean isQEmp()
   {
      return sllq.isEmpty();
   }

   public void insert(int val){
      sllq.insertF(val);
      count++;

   }

   public int remove() {

      count--;
      return sllq.removeL();
   }
   public int displayQF() {

      return sllq.displayFQ();
   }

   public int displayQR(){

      return sllq.displayRQ();
   }


   public void displayQ() {
      sllq.displayLinkedListQ();
   }
```

```html
class Node{
   public  int qdata;
   public  Node next;

   public  Node(int n){ 
      qdata = n;          
   }

   public void displayN()
   {
      System.out.print(qdata +  "");
   }
}


public class SinglyLinkedListQueue{
   Node front;
   Node rear;

   public SinglyLinkedListQueue(){ 
      front = null;
      rear = null; 
   }


   public void insertF(int a){
      Node newNode = new Node(a);
      newNode.next=null;
      if(isEmpty())
         front = newNode;
      else
         rear.next = newNode;
      rear = newNode;
   }


   public int removeL(){


      int b = front.qdata;
      if(front.next == null)
         rear = null;
      front = front.next;

      return b;
   }       

   public int displayFQ() {

      if(isEmpty()== true)

         System.out.print("The Queue is empty, excpetion thrown");
      return front.qdata;

   }


   public int displayRQ() {


      Node current = front;
      while(current != rear && isEmpty() != true){
         current = current.next;
      }

      System.out.println("Queue is empty, exception thrown\n");

      return current.qdata;

   }



   public void displayLinkedListQ() {
      Node current = front; 
      while(current != null){
            System.out.print(current.qdata + " ");
            current = current.next;
        }
      System.out.println();

   }

   public boolean isEmpty()
   {
      return (front == null);
   }

}
```

Comment: are you asking us for code review?

Comment: Yes! I have some issues with my code I am trying to fix

Comment: There is a better place for that: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh I did not know that! Thanks :)

Comment: @SashaSalauyou "I have some issues with my code I am trying to fix" - nope. [codereview.se] is for code that's *ready for a peer review* - that's *code that already works as intended*. Please see [a guide to CR for SO users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788) on CR.Meta for all the details.